# Anyone have idea with this command?

Tags: caching, scp

I will be introduced with .csp file by Cache

Can you help elaborate their coding linem what was that initials (w, q, k, d, s etc )

```
    w "<th>Total (RM)</th>"
    q

#;=====================================
#;knjlbbk
#;===================================== 
xxfindSomthingSomthing(dateFrom,dateTo,Status,currentPage,sessionId,type)
    n (dateFrom,dateTo,Status,%request)
    d insertAudit^exyz,abcabc(126,43,"",$$getSession^eaa.Audit(sessionId,type),"")
    k ^Temp

    d paginationInit^eaa.Pagination($g(currentPage))
    s dataCount = 0
    s list = ""
    f
    {
```

Answer (score -1):

> s stand for set
>   w is write
>   q is quit

that's all you know.

Comment: how about n and d and k?